# xiaomi Power bank for Rapberry pi 3

Tags: power-supply

Will this power bank **Original Xiaomi 20000mAh DC5.1V 3.6A Dual USB Output Fast Charge Power Bank** work with raspberry pi 3? If so how long will it last? Do we need any extra circuit between rpi and power bank?

Comment: The point of the duplicate here is that regardless of the numbers on it a powerbank may not be up to snuff for a Pi 3.  They're intended to recharge other batteries, not actually power a live device (these are two different goals that may be reflected in the circuitry).  That said, *if* anything will work a 5.1 V 3.6A bank should.  You then want to watch if the red power led flickers while in operation; this indicates under voltage which will happen if the bank cannot properly respond to surges in current draw.

Comment: Will overpower burn rapberry pi really?

Comment: I didn't write that, I wrote *under voltage*.  If you mean because the bank is 3.6A that's not how electricity works; this is the most current the powerbank can deliver, which is enough for a Pi.  However, how much it can deliver from *one port* is another question, and as to whether it can deliver enough instantaneous current is another question.  Because power banks are intended for recharging other batteries, they are generally specialized to *prevent*, e.g., current surges.  So as I wrote before, this is a different goal than powering a live device.

Comment: I.e., you are not buying something intended to power electronics, and you *may* be disappointed.    I have a 20000 mAh 5V powerbank, and it works with other Pis, but not a Pi 3 -- at least not very well as the *under voltage warning* is frequently triggered.  Other people have reported the same problem.  But not all powerbanks are the same; unfortunately the numbers (5.1V 3.6A) are not a certain way to tell which ones will work and which ones won't.